# is it possible to retrieve image from sql server management using java code and display in jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, sql-server-2014

Hai iam struct to display images in jsp page...i insert the images into sql server management studio and the image datatype is image...i write the insertion code to insert the image and whenever i am calling to images from database it is not displaying in the jsp pages and getting the error is

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7069632E6A7067"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

jsp view page code

```
<table id="basicTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
                            <thead class="">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Profile Picture</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                      <%   
                          int s=0;
                          String s2="",s3="",s4="",s5="";
                          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                        String connectionUrl;
                        connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS14;databaseName=Student;user=XX;password=XXXX";
                        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                // Statement st = con.createStatement();
              PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
              pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from  login_users "); //sql select query
              ResultSet rs1=pstmt.executeQuery(); //execute query and set in ResultSet object "rs"
            %>
            <tbody>
            <%
            while(rs1.next())
           {
                    s=rs1.getInt(1);
        s2=rs1.getString(2);
        s3=rs1.getString(3);
        s4=rs1.getString(4);
        s5=rs1.getString(5);
            %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%=s%> </td>
                                    <td><%=s2%></td>
                                    <td><%=s3%></td>
                                    <td><%=s4%></td>
<td><div align="center"><input  name="image" type="image" src="print_image.jsp?imgid=<%=s5%>" width="100" height="100" alt="Submit"></div></td>

                                <%
            }                                     
         %>    
                                </tr>
                              
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

and print_image.jsp code is

```
int id =  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("imgid"));
try
    {     
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx\\SQLEXPRESS14;databaseName=Student;user=xx;password=XXXX");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String strQuery = "select image from login_users where id='"+id+"'" ;

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    String imgLen="";
    if(rs.next())
    {
        imgLen = rs.getString(1);
    }  
    rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    if(rs.next())
    {         

        int len = imgLen.length();
        byte [] rb = new byte[len];
        InputStream readImg = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
        int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
                    //System.out.println("index"+index);
        st.close();
        response.reset();
            //response.setContentType("image/jpg");
        response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len); 
        response.getOutputStream().flush();   
    }
}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

%>

Comment: Hi what is `s5` ?

Comment: i am storing the value in s5 (it is user defined variable)  s = ID, s2=name, s3= address, s4=phone number, s5 = profile picture

Comment: As you can see here`7069632E6A7067` is not integer it has alphabet in it that's the reason its giving you `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: how can i resolve it and view the picture in google chrome

Comment: what is datatype of `id` column  ?

Comment: i am using sql server management studio 2014 database and the id datatype is integer....image datatype is image...

Comment: so does `7069632E6A7067` exist in your table ? Also try changing id type to varchar see if that works . Then you can just pass string value no need to parse

Comment: it is not working....i change the code in print_image.jsp like this i am calling the image with the help of name instead of id and the NumberFormatException doesn't come but images are not displaying in chrome

Comment: Change `<input  name="image" type="image" src="print_image.jsp?imgid=<%=s5%>" width="100" height="100" alt="Submit">` to `<img src="print_image.jsp?.." width="100" height="100" alt="Submit">` you need to use `img` tag not input tag.

Comment: images are not displaying

Comment: hai Swati i have change the code in the print_image.jsp page from second if loop  byte[] bytearray = new byte[4096];  int size=0;  InputStream sImage = rs.getBinaryStream(1);  response.reset(); response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); while((size=sImage.read(bytearray))!= -1){ response.getOutputStream().write(bytearray,0,size); } response.getOutputStream().flush(); response.getOutputStream().close(); response.flushBuffer(); sImage.close(); rs.close();  and it is working....